# React Native FlashList "flickers" with state change

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flash-list

I am currently using FlashList to show a list of results retrieved from the device's native contact list. The idea is when you select a contact(s) there is a checkbox that appears to each contact indicating it's select. However after this implementation, I have noticed that FlashList component flickers with each selection. I quickly switched to the React Native FlatList with no problems, so it clearly has to do with FlashList specifically.

I have verified that I have defined a unique key using the `keyExtractor` prop, and I have set the `extraData` prop using the selected data. Based on what I read from the documentation, this should have solved my issue but it did not. Any help would be appreciated.

#### My Component View

```html
<View style={{ display: 'flex', flex: 1, width: '100%', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
                    <FlashList
                        data={contacts}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}-${index}`}
                        ref={contactList}
                        extraData={selectedContacts}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        estimatedItemSize={100}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
```

#### Component Code

```js
const contactList = useRef()
const [selectedContacts, setSelectedContacts] = useState<string[]>([]);

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <ContactListResult item={item}
                           onPress={toggleSelection}
                           selectable={true}
                           selected={selectedContacts.indexOf(item.id) >= 0}
        />
    );

const toggleSelection = (item : ConnectionListItem) => {
        let currentList = [...selectedContacts];
        if (currentList.includes(item.id)) {
            currentList.splice(currentList.indexOf(item.id), 1)
        } else {
            currentList.push(item.id)
        }
        setSelectedContacts(currentList)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a re-render here: `selectedContacts passed as extraData -> setSelectedContacts called from the rendered item -> selectedContacts updates and triggers re-rendering of FlashList`

---

Possible solution: don't pass `selectedContacts` as `extraData`, simply indicate selection by checkbox in UI + call `setSselectedContacts`. Process `selectedContacts` later in a callback function

Rewrite this function to avoid updating the callback too often:

```
const toggleSelection = useCallback((item : ConnectionListItem) => {
   setSelectedContacts((currentList) => currentList.push(item.id))
}, [])
```

Rewrite your component to simply display UI logic:

```
        <ContactListResult item={item}
                           onPress={toggleSelection}
                           selectable={true}
    // don't pass `selected`, make `const displayCheckbox = useState(false)` 
    // inside this component and trigger checkbox appearing 
    // `if (displayCheckbox !== true) return null` when the user pressed ListItem
        />
```

Later in your callback function (where you use `selectedContacts`) simply call `[...Set(selectedContacts]` to filter duplicates of `item.id`

Comment: I have made the changes as you suggested. When used without any state changes in the root component, the `ContactListResult` works great. The checkbox is appearing as desired. Unfortunately however, the `toggleSelection` suggestion, as written, is inducing a flicker on the first tap, and the second tap induces a Render Error: `undefined is not a function`. The error indicates that currentList.push is not a function. After some logging, the state is being set to null after the initial tap. All in all, the suggestion doesn't work unfortunately.